# why is a day's first page load a white screen filled with characters?

Tags: 7

often when loading our Drupal 7 development site for the first time in the morning OR for the first time any given browser has been used in a while, we get a white screen filled with a large assortment of characters (see example below).

This has been the case for several months and doesn't seem to have corresponded to a particular change we made. It is definitely NOT browser specific; has been the case through multiple D7 core updates; we only work on Win7 so not sure if it would be the same on a Mac. In any case, the very next page load consistently loads the site correctly, but, of course, I'm concerned about end users having an experience like this once the site goes live.

Has anyone else experienced this or know what the cause and cure are?

[image: Example]

Comment: You have page caching turned on, correct?  I am nearly sure that this is the cause, but I don't know why it happens on some sites, but not others.

Comment: I let this lie dormant because I wanted to test what would happen when caching was off. So, yeah, turning off caching eliminated the problem. However, I can't see us going live without turning caching back on -- Drupal is just too bulky / slow. Anyone have a solution for how to eliminate the above problem without disabling caching?